# Mysql Convert_tz

Tags: mysql, convert-tz

I'm trying to convert a datetime from Asia/Manila to EST timezone
without declaring the exact interval like
`date_sub(), subdate(), date_add(), adddate()`

i find it easy to use 
`SELECT DATE_SUB('2016-04-04 13:00:00', INTERVAL 12 HOUR);`

the result will be`2016-04-04 01:00:00`

But Im trying to create a dynamic script where i don't need to look how many hours is the difference between two timezone 
and i find `Convert_TZ()` to do job
`SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-04 13:00:00', 'Asia/Manila', 'EST');`

but the result of this query is `2016-04-04 00:00:00`
Maybe this native function is not including the "Daylight saving time(DST)"

Does anyone know how to do the trick?

 where i can easily convert the time including the DST
to any timezone without hard coding the interval hour between the two timezone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my problem is solved,  i use two option

First :
I simply use 'US/Eastern' not 'EST' to include the daylight in conversion.

Second:

Because I didn't know the first option earlier i do this to solve my problem at first.

I create a table that compose of the date where it is DST
which i found in some site online..

[image]

 
Then
I create a mysql function where its lookup to the table above 
which if the specified date is between that DST Start and DST End it will automatically add  1 hour,

My function is like this,

`CREATE FUNCTION usp_Convert(specified_date DATETIME, From_Timezone VARCHAR(20), To_Timezone VARCHAR(20), is_DST INT(1)) RETURNS datetime`

`DECLARE theDate DATETIME;` 
 `SET theDate = CONVERT_TZ(specified_date, From_Timezone, To_Timezone);`

`IF is_DST = 1 AND To_Timezone= 'EST' THEN` 
 `SET theDate = ADDDATE(theDate, INTERVAL 1 HOUR);` 
 `END IF;`
 `RETURN theDate;`

This might not be the best answer but this totally solved my problem

Thanks.